# How to disable automatic TAB change and just do it from code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I put txt1(NSTextFiled),txt2 (NSTextField) , tbl1 (NSTableView) on view1,when cursor is in txt1,I push TAB key  and cursor goes to txt2.i want to change it from code that when i push TAB i go to tbl1 (tbl1 becomes first responder), then i subclass txt1 to `customtext` and implement below code in it

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:))
    {
            [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(pressTAB) withObject:nil ];
    }//if
    . . .
}
```

and i implement `pressTAB` method in view1 and write below code

```
-(void)pressTAB
{
    [[self.view window] makeFirstResponder:self.tbl1];
}
```

everything is ok and code works properly but after this code run Xcode automatically change first responder to txt2. how can i disable automatic TAB change and just do it from my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in code by setting the nextKeyView property (using Xcode 4.2 it doesn't seem to work to do this in IB). So:

txt1.nextKeyView = tbl1;

Comment: You should be able to -- there is an outlet for it in the connections inspector, but as I said in my answer, I tried it and it didn't work.